# CSS: Scroll on fixed position menu overlay without 2 scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue where a fixed-position menu needs to be scrolled, but the outer body already has scrollbars. Even if I remove the outer body's scrollbars then the menu div's scrollbars intersect with the "Close" button, which itself is fixed at the top-right of the screen.

From the image you can see that there are two scrollbars and the inner bar intersects the "Close" button. I'd like to have only 1 scrollbar and no intersect. However, when the menu is closed the scrollbar needs to scroll the page, and when the menu is open it needs to scroll the menu (which is in a fixed position div.)

Is there a way I can use the scrollbar from the entire page to scroll the page when the menu is closed and to scroll only the menu when the menu is open?

Or is there another way to achieve the desired effect?

[image]

Comment: Please provide code we can work with

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I suggest to *freeze* the webpage behind the menu when the menu is open:

```
  var top;
  function menuOpen() {
      top = $("body").scrollTop();
      $("html").css({"position":"fixed", "top":-top});
  }
  function menulose() {
      $("html").css({"position":"static", "top":0});
      $("html, body").scrollTop(top);
  }
```

Following css is required for it to work properly:

```
html {
    width: 100%
    height: 100%;
}
```

Let me know if this code works, if not it migth be required to add overflow hidden to menuOpen and overflow auto/scroll to menuClose.

Answer (score 0):

The close button is probably a whole different issue, post a link to the code or the website so we can look into that properly...